# html URL: '%23' not converted to #

Tags: html

A webpage is opened if the URL contains '#'. But i get 'Page Not Found' error if the url contains '%23' instead of #.

Few months earlier, i was able to access my html page using the following link '%23'. 
`https://www.something.com/index.html%23MyPage`

however, these links are now not working. but works if %23 is changed to #.
`https://www.something.com/index.html#MyPage`

curious, what could be the reason. Could it be something changed in the webserver? I have such links specified in many places and do not want to change if possible.

Will appreciate your help.

Comment: `%23` is the _encoded_ version of `#`, so it cannot function as a fragment identifier anymore. Why do you have these links and what do you mean by “earlier”? What kind of answers do you expect to this question? Please [edit] your question and provide more context.

Comment: Updated the question. just wondering if something changed in the Webserver where html pages are or something changed in the Browser itself.

Comment: Are these links generated by code somewhere?  Usually the `#` will redirect to a named element on the page.  As for using `%23`, why would you?  I could understand if you had a variable in there, something like `?page=mypage.html` or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using %23 instead of # is not possible. The whole purpose of URL encoded strings is that they should not have any function in the URL itself, so that you can pass letters to the URL which normally have functions.

For example ? / #. If these characters aren't encoded, the URL wants to treat them according to their function. So what if you want to use one of these characters without their function? You use encoded characters which will have no functions and are simply treated as strings.

Comment: I don't know about OP, but we have some crappy old web page building software (Logi) that allows you to intput URLs as hyperlinks. This software is converting the # to %23 and it breaks the link. 

I appreciate the insight that encoded characters are not interpretted as functions in the browser, but will rather be passed to the website server as a string request, which is obviously the reason it's 404-ing.